# Increment a value like 'CJana001' in delphi object pascal

Tags: delphi, increment

My DB returns me a value like 'CJana001' and now i wanted to increment this to 'CJana002' and insert a new row and save in DB(MySql) back, this 'CJana001' is of string type.

Max increment would be limited in a range of 001 to 999,It should not increment after CJana999. and the CJana may vary depending on user selection. the maximum length of the string without numbers is 5 and minimum length is 1.

CJana001 may anything like C_Lang001 or C++001 or PHP001 etc..

How to handle this in Delphi Programming?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried using inc() , but it not worked out..

Comment: What was your effort to solve this problem?

Comment: I tried by Splitting string and adding back, but some where i got missed,,

Comment: You might take this as an opportunity to refactor the database and your object models into something more sane.  It's a lot easier to store an integer as an integer and to link it to other data rather than confusing the issue by burying it in a string.  Store ingredients instead of soup - then the problem of un-making the soup goes away.

Comment: You just want us to write your code for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like you would handle it in any other language as well: start with the last byte and increment it. If it's already the highest then set it to the lowest and repeat your workflow with the byte before. If there is no more byte before, add a new byte in front with the lowest value.

"Highest" and "lowest" are freely definable - in an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) world (and sticking to your example) I suggest using $30..$39, $41..$5A and $61..$7A. And as you tagged it **Delphi** I'd define a String constant just holding these bytes so you can easily access them from first to last.

Edit: thanks to your clarifications in comments it'd be easier to just do this:

```
var
  iNumber: Integer;
  sOld, sNew: String;
begin
  sOld:= 'CJana001';  // Wherever this comes from
  iNumber:= StrToInt( Copy( sOld, Length( sOld )- 2, 3 ) );  // Grab number part
  if iNumber< 999 then Inc( iNumber );  // Prevent overflow
  sNew:= IntToStr( iNumber );
  while Length( sNew )< 3 do sNew:= '0'+ sNew;  // Grow to 3 digits
  sNew:= Copy( sOld, 1, Length( sOld )- 3 )+ sNew;  // Prepend text part
```

Comment: Your Code is working fine ,but the number may start at any position, but not at Zero position,There would atleast be a single string value. it will be like C001,CP0001,CPP001,CJava001, How can we handle this with your code snip.

Comment: Inspect the last character: is it `'0'..'9'` advance to previous. And so on, until it doesn't match. That gives you starting position and length of what to grab.

Comment: Are there any functions to do as u said. can you please refer me.

Comment: The only thing that may not know is: `sOld[iPos]` can be used to operate on single characters of a String. Now you have everything: you get the length via `Length()`, you can copy portions via `Copy()`, and casting from String to Integer and vice versa can be done thru the two `XToY()` functions.

Comment: Hello  @AmigoJack.. I just done two small modifications to your snippet and it is working for all my cases.. Thank You. I will add those updations in your snippet above