# generate a number increases with a specific format ex 'PRT-00000'

Tags: delphi

I want to create auto numbering to my access database in delphi
example :

I have a database with part names , i want to create an auto id that counts number of these records and generates a name with number as this 'PRT-00000' and increase it with one each time i add a record and keeps this format of five digits , like this 'PRT-00001'

help me please and thanks a lot .

sorry for my poor english

Comment: An auto-increment column can only be an integer not a string. But you can create a separate calculated string column that incorporates the auto-incremented column as part of its value.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increment a value like 'CJana001' in delphi object pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216860/increment-a-value-like-cjana001-in-delphi-object-pascal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your Access table is named 'Parts' and has an AutoNumber
field named 'ID' and a Short Text field named 'PartNumber'.  One way of generating the
PartNumber value would be to get Access to calculate it for you, but since you have asked about Delphi, I'm going to explain a way to do it in Delphi.

Please start a new, very simple project with just the following items on the main form:

- A TAdoConnection configured to connect to your database;
- A TAdoQuery configured to use the TAdoConnection with its SQL.Text property set
  to 'select * from Parts'
- A TDataSource and TDBGrid configured to display the contents of the TAdoQuery.
- A TButton

Then, add the following code to the form's unit:

```
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  NewPart;
end;

procedure TForm2.NewPart;
const
  sSelect = 'select * from Parts';
  sPrefix = 'PRT-';
  iDigits = 5;
var
  PartNumber : String;
  ID : Integer;
begin
  qryParts.Insert;

  try
    //  First, set the new record's PartNumber field to a temporary value
    qryParts.FieldByName('PartNumber').AsString := 'xxxx';

    // save the record so that we can then read the ID value Access has allocated to the record
    qryParts.Post;

    // read the ID value

    ID := qryParts.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;

    //  next, construct the desired value for the PartNumber field based on the ID
    PartNumber := qryParts.FieldByName('ID').AsString;

    //  left-pad the PartNumber with zeroes
    while Length(PartNumber) < iDigits do
      PartNumber := '0' + PartNumber;

    // pre-pend the PRT- prefix
    PartNumber := sPrefix + PartNumber;

    // put qryParts into its dsEdit state
    qryParts.Edit;
    qryParts.FieldByName('PartNumber').AsString := PartNumber;

  finally
     // post the record back to the Parts table
    qryParts.Post;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  qryParts.Open;
end;
```

**Update** I've managed to get the new Part's autonumber ID in advance of the new Part being posted to the db.  To use this, add the `NewAutoNumber` function and modify the `NewPart` method as shown below.

```
function TForm2.NewAutoNumber(ATable, AColumn: String): Integer;
var
  vCat : OleVariant;
  vTable : OleVariant;
  vColumn : OleVariant;
begin
  vCat := CreateOleObject('ADOX.Catalog');
  vCat.ActiveConnection := AdoConnection1.ConnectionString;
  vTable := vCat.Tables[ATable];
  vColumn := vTable.Columns[AColumn];
  Result := vColumn.Properties['Seed'].Value;
end;

procedure TForm2.NewPart;
const
  sSelect = 'select * from Parts';
  sPrefix = 'PRT-';
  iDigits = 5;
var
  PrvSql : String;
  PartNumber : String;
  ID : Integer;
begin
  ID := NewAutoNumber('Parts', 'ID');
  try
    qryParts.Insert;
    qryParts.FieldByName('PartNumber').AsString := 'xxxx';
    qryParts.Post;

    if not qryParts.Locate('ID', ID, []) then begin
      raise exception.CreateFmt('Failed to create new Parts record with ID = %d', [ID]);
    end;

    PartNumber := qryParts.FieldByName('ID').AsString;

    while Length(PartNumber) < iDigits do
      PartNumber := '0' + PartNumber;
    PartNumber := sPrefix + PartNumber;

    qryParts.Edit;
    qryParts.FieldByName('PartNumber').AsString := PartNumber;
  finally
    qryParts.Post;
  end;
end;
```

**Update #2** As an alternative to getting the ID value for a newly-added Parts record using
either of the methods above, it can be obtained by using the 'select @@identity' method.  The simplest
way to do this is to add another TAdoQuery, qryAutoNumber to the form and to add this function to
get the AutoNumber value:

```
function TForm2.NewAutoNumberFromIdentity : Integer;
begin
  if qryAutoNumber.Active then
    qryAutoNumber.Close;
  qryAutoNumber.SQL.Text := 'select @@identity';
  qryAutoNumber.Open;
  Result := qryAutoNumber.Fields[0].AsInteger;
end;
```

Note that to obtain the correct ID value, this function should be called **immediately after** calling `qryParts.Post`.  However, I have included this
only for completeness but as far as I can see, it is largely pointless
because once the new Parts record has been posted, the ID AutoNumber value
can be read directly from the `ID` field of `qryParts`.

Comment: Thank you very much